# How to enable google play store app if it has been remove from some country?

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-application

I am android app developer.
My one app has been removed from google play store in some country reason for alleged trademark infringement. i use name as picart.
So is there any solution for re enable my app in all country?

Comment: change application name and submit update. will work probably if you still have older version there on play store

Comment: @vrundpurohit Is it enable in all country if i change name and update?

Comment: you can give a shot. otherwise you have to change package name and republish app. or you can also contact Google team for issue. see with what they can help you out.

Comment: can we change package name of existing app?

Comment: Can we set "com.joy.picart" package name?

Comment: you can use any unique package name.. Just don't use content which may causes copyright issues. like in your case you named you app "picart". which is clearly similar to "picsart", which is well known image editing app.

Comment: oh thanks dear :-) @vrundpurohit